# Partitioned download of a CSV using S3A from S3 object storage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am looking to download a file that has been saved to s3 using partitioned upload. I tried to add `*` at the end of my address but it looks like this format is not valid. My code is as follows:

```
df= spark.read.csv('s3a://bucket-name/file.csv/*')
                         , header='true'
                         , inferSchema ='true'
                        )
```

The files are stored with the following:

```
file.csv/part1.csv
file.csv/part2.csv
```

I'm wondering whether using `*` is supported or not. And if not, what is an alternative?

Comment: I'd avoid using inferSchema, as it means "read the entire file top to bottom to guess its schema", before actually doing any work.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try just giving up to directory location like below instead specifying the '*' character,

```
val df=spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true) 
  .csv("s3a://bucket-name/file.csv/")
```